# Delphi package problem : Packaged units must refer only to packaged units.. (E2411)

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, delphi-xe

The error I get is like this:

`[DCC Fatal Error] myunit3.pas(244): E2411 Unit XBAT in package B_Dsgn refers to unit QBEE which is not found in any package.  Packaged units must refer only to packaged units`

I need to know what this error I am encountering really means, and if possible how to troubleshoot and solve such problems, especially when the facts stated in the error message are not correct (the units are in fact referring to other units in other valid packages).

Such problems involve package dependencies.  I am having an interesting problem with a series of three designtime and three runtime packages related like this:

[image]

What is most odd about it is that each time I clean and rebuild, I get a different unit name in the error. (Shown above as Unit XBAT refers to unit QBEE).

The other odd thing is that it's referring to units that are in a top level dependency, and are part of a package that was already built.

Steps;

1. Compile A, it works.
2. Compile A_Dsgn, it works.
3. Compile B, it Works.
4. Compile B_Dsgn, it works.
5. Compile C, and it fails with this E2411 error.

Since I doubt anybody can tell me how to fix this exactly, I am looking for the steps to troubleshoot a complex dependency problem in a package. The literal meaning of the above error suggests for example, that I should have a corresponding message about an implicit linked unit, which I do not have. I have added all implicitly used units to the base packages A, and B, so that no implicit unit warnings are made.

My next idea was to separate the DCU output folders for each package, to prevent the DCU outputs from one from confusing the compiler.  Now I can not even build the packages.

**Update**  I tried playing with the `Explicit Rebuild` and `Rebuild as Needed` options.  I have found that this error is related to having 'Rebuild as Needed' turned on. When it is turned off, the packages fail with other errors which are more to the point.  I find it odd that the compiler emits weird errors that can be disabled by turning off `Rebuild as needed`.  Any ideas what is going on?

**Update 2** The basic underlying problem is not solved by turning on or off explicit rebuild. Instead of getting this error, I get annoying runtime/designtime package problems, which result in a set of packages, that can not be loaded at the same time. (Can not load package foo because it contains unit bar which is also in package bat. Do you want to attempt to load this package the next time a project is loaded?).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, when "Rebuild as Needed" is checked, then building C triggers a rebuild of B, which subsequently triggers a rebuild of B_Dsgn (which fails) - are you sure you haven't introduced some kind of circular dependency from C/C_Dsgn to B/B_Dsgn?

Comment: Are you using [weak packaging](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Weak_packaging)?

Comment: Good question.Tomorrow at work I will search for references to weak packaging.

Comment: @TOndrej: I can't see how weak pacakging has anything to do with it. That doesn't change which unit is in which package's contains and which units are referenced. It only changes how units are linked in (either always, as part of the BPL or only when needed, copied from the .dcp file and linked in directly).

Comment: FWIW, in which package is QBEE and in which package is XBAT?

Comment: I have found many many references to WeakPackageLink and removed them experimentally.  This error goes away, and instead the entire IDE crashes, each time I build.

Comment: IMO, it is a delphi compiler bug.

Comment: I see you use XE. But I have the same problem here with XE7. Damn, when a bug is introduced in Delphi, it sticks for at least 7 versions!!! Update: more than 7 versions since Cochran confirms it on Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it is an obscure compiler bug.

The project I experienced it in had at least 4 levels of dependent runtime packages:

PackageA <- PackageB <- PackageC <- PackageD

> E2411 Unit '%s' in package PackageD refers to unit '%s' which is not
>   found in any package. Packaged units must refer only to packaged units.

The only solution I found that worked was to make packages A, B and C never-build (i.e. Explicit Build) packages and use [Project Dependencies](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Project_Dependencies)  to enforce build order instead. I had to make all three never-build or I would get

> E2220 Never-build package '%s' requires always-build package '%s'

I know its probably not the answer you were looking for but there it is.

Btw, this happened to me in Delphi 2009.

Comment: This is consistent with my experience. I wish I could produce a portable reproducible instance of this bug, so I could report it in QC.

Comment: I find the docwiki quite helpful here: never build means the interface is fixed, while always build means it is still in development: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_nobuild_requires_xml.html

Comment: That's what the docs say. What I think it really means is "the dependency management system in Delphi is subtly broken and needs repair, but until we fix it you can turn this off when you finish development on a project, and we'll do fewer useless full rebuilds when our dependency system fails in a stuck-on fashion".

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. I ran into the sample problem in Delphi XE2 and your suggestion worked.

Comment: Damn. This solution will not work for me, since Package A contains utilities often used/updated/improved. Package A must always compile! And everybody depends on Package A.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple: If a unit in C refers to a unit not in any package referred to by package C, that unit should be included in C, or the package in which it can be found should be referenced by C. If necessary, put the unit in a package of its own.

Where you put which unit depends on the dependencies. It makes sense to draw it out, like you did, but with a unit level resolution.

### Update

Your update 1 and update 2 still make me think there is a unit one of your units uses (directly **or indirectly**) that is not properly referenced. Perhaps even an RTL or VCL unit. Since you have design packages, I assume you have components in them.

IME, the minimum set of packages to include is

```
requires
  rtl,
  designide,
  vcl,
  vclactnband,
  vclx,
  xmlrtl;
```

Comment: I am saying that I understand that is the literal meaning of this error message, however, that in this case, all such units are duly included (explicitly) in each package, and that there are no such implicit or missing units.

Comment: But are all packages referenced that must be referenced? If not, a unit may be linked in directly.

Comment: I believe so, but it is very very difficult to verify that.  In addition to the usual VCl suspects you listed, there are over 100 other packages in this "code ecosystem" any of which could be housing a unit that thus creates a missed-dependency.  Since the units in question have been carefully verified, it seems that missed dependencies other than the ones in the error messages indicates a compiler bug of some kind.

Comment: I hardly believe in a compiler bug, in this case. If I see something like it happening, IME it is a bug in my setup.

Comment: Both are possible at once.  The bug in my setup is almost undiscoverable due to a lack of correct compiler error messages. The normal "implicit import" warnings are not happening, and something else is going wrong at the same time, and the wrong error message is coming out.  No amount of fiddling with other options can coax a correct package message from the setup.

Comment: @Warren: Hmmm... Can't tell what is going on there, sorry. The "implicit" warning should at least happen once.

Comment: I had a package of 10 units that only require VclSmp.dcp

Answer (score 1):

In the project that gives the error must be added as required the. dcp error.

In your case:

[DCC Fatal Error] myunit3.pas (244): E2411 Unit in package B_Dsgn XBAT Refers to unit QBEE Which is not found in Any package. Must Refer Packaged units only to packaged units

In the package where it myunit3.pas drive, add in required: QBEE

At least I managed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **QBEE** unit in the unit **XBAT**, in this case you have foure options:

1- you didn't add the **QBEE** to the *contains* list in the Package **B_Dsgn**.

2- If **QBEE** is already containd in another Package lets call it **Original_Package** then you should add the Package to the *requires* list in **B_Dsgn** and not contain the unit.

3- the **Original_Package** has

**`{$IMPLICITBUILD ON}`**

in it's dpk file so first what you have to do is to turn `IMPLICITBUILD` off and build **Original_Package** after that you can build your **B_Dsgn** package.

4-you probably didn't have **XBAT** in **B_Dsgn** but you have it in another middle package lets call it **B_Run** and you have **B_Run** in the requires list of **B_Dsgn**, in this case try first to fix **B_Run** with one of the upper three options and then build it, after that you can build **B_Dsgn**.

**Note:**

- the last two cases could be reproduced with a long list of units and not just two or three packages that are requiring each other, in this case all of the packages should have `IMPLICITBUILD` off.
- Clean the code for every single package of the packages that effect the issue before building them.

good luck